# Once I use array.prototype.map/filter on an array, is it possible to convert it back to the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a FreeCodeCamp algorithm that asks me to do the following:

**Remove all falsy values from an array.**

**Falsy values in JavaScript are false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN.**

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  // First thing I did was change the arr argument into an array that changed all the values into true or false.
  var newArr = arr.map(function(elements) {
    return Boolean(elements);
  });
  // Now that all the elements are easily filterable, I did that exactly.

  var filterArr = newArr.filter(function(value) {
    return value === true;
    /*Freecodecamp keeps telling me to use '==' here instead of '==='. I know the difference between 
    the strict equality operator and the equality operator, but wouldn't '==' work just as well? 
    */ 
  });
  /* Now filterArr outputs [true, true, true]. 

     Is there anyway to somehow reverse the map method I used earlier
     so that it 'converts' the [true, true, true] array into [7, "ate", 9] as the output?
  */
  return filterArr;
}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

So while I managed to remove the falsy values, I don't know how to convert the filtered array back into the original array respectively. I would like to figure this out on my own, but I'm a bit stuck.

If there is another method I should've used?

Apologies if the code looks like crap. I tried using comments to explain my train of thought and questions.

Comment: no, of course it's not possible - you've destroyed that information.  You should just do `return arr.filter(el => el)`

Comment: `filter()` and `map()` return a new array, they don't affect the original array in any way, so your original array, `arr` is intact. I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish anyway, you want to filter the array only to restore it to its original state? What's the point?

Comment: The original state minus the falsy values. @MikaelLennholm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter the array you've got, relying on the fact that `.filter` will take the result of the callback as a boolean:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(value) {
        return value;
    });
}
```

or in ES6 syntax:

```
let bouncer = (arr) => arr.filter(v => v);
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking! Your answer makes much more sense!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's pretty much as easy as this, right?

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9, 0, NaN, true, Infinity, null, undefined, {}]));
```

Comment: there's no need to convert to `Boolean` - the `.filter` function does that implicitly to the callback's return value

Comment: @Alnitak yes, I'm aware, but to a beginner, the _intention_ of returning the element itself may not be obvious, so casting it to a `Boolean` draws attention to the fact that its truthiness is what determines the action of `filter()`. But that gave me an idea, see my edit.

Comment: It's in the documentation

Comment: @Alnitak "RTFM" is not an excuse for obscuring intention where it's trivial to show.

Answer (score 0):

Since good answers suggesting the use of `filter()` have already been presented, I'll present a solution for when you'd actually want to modify the original array, which is unusual and best avoided but has valid use cases none the less:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i]) {
      i++;
    } else {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but don't even run this on a JS interpreter where `Array.prototype.splice` is an `O(n)` operation... :p